# how shoud i create/construct/assign a large vector of hardcoded values?

Tags: c++, vector, initialization, construct

I haven't been coding C++ long enough to know what is a good way to do this, so any and all advice is appreciated.

The vector is a list of option names, types, and values. It is hardcoded to allow for sensible values without any user specification, and as a fallback for when user's option file is missing or etc.

I would like to assign the entire vector to a public member variable of another object in a different class. The options don't necessarily need to be in a class; i'd be happy with a namespace. Ideally I would like to assign the entire vector with one large initialization, like

```
    vec = {
       { name1, val1, ... },
       .
       .
       .
       { nameN, valN, ... }
    };
```

but a bunch of push_back()s would be ok too. After initialization i will read the options file and overwrite values as they are encountered.

Associated with this vector will be 3 functions: 1) Search for option by name, which will be used by 2) return integer value and 3) return string value. (Edit: no option will have both an int and a string value.)

Ultimately none of these ideas are set in concrete so if anybody has other thoughts I would be happy to hear them.

Comment: Where are these hardcode values being stored? Would they need to be read in from a file or are known beforehand? Also the operations you mention on the vector aren't well suited for a vector. Probably look at [`std::unordered_set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) for faster lookup?

Comment: ok will look at unordered set. options are hardcoded in the source and overwriteable by user file

Comment: I recommend that you encapsulate your options in your own class, so that no part of your code needs to care about the underlying container (except the options class itself of course).  The inside the class you are free to use whatever you like.  `std::unordered_set` is often a good choice, depending on what other requirements you may have.  The point is that if your requirements grow beyond this data structure's capability, then you won't have to modify everywhere in your program that uses the options.  All you'll need to do is change your options class implementation.

Comment: If it's hardcoded, you could just as well write something like what you've written and make it static within the class whose object you want to assign it to or perhaps even just use the hardcoded set directly from your object, avoiding copies etc..

Comment: Re encapsulation: this is my preferred way, but i havent figured out how to avoid using a member variable in the options class, which would leave me referencing   
  main_class_instance->opts_member_variable->opts_class_instance_variable->opt_name->opt_value. Too much dereferencing for my taste. Otoh, static is something that i know how to do but then i give up encapsulation and the main class is huge already without subsuming the option data and logic.

Comment: Ok, i just figured out that using std::map will obviate the need for separate search and return functions. How awesome. But still there are the questions as to whether and how to encapsulate.

Comment: resolution: i went with std::map<string, opt_struct> (which i typdefed), put the struct and typedef declarations in a .h file, and made the init_opts and read_opts member functions of the class that owns the opts member variable. The init function has to use map::insert 'cause sticking a huge initializer list at the variable declaration would have been extremely ungainly. Thanks for your comments, folks.

Answer (score 0):

see "resolution" in above comments